# How to use object oriented without using keyword ('new')

Tags: javascript, oop

What am I trying to do is as following:

```
var Person = function(name) {
   this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function () {
   return this.name;
}

// This will return error;
console.log(Person('John').getName());
// While this won't.
var p1 = new Person('john');
console.log(p1.getName());
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: When you use `new`, an instance is created and functions defined in prototype are available for objects

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using `new`?

Comment: @mattBrowne That's it, I am trying to get rid of new without returning any error. I just showed a small example while I am trying to make a library for a new project.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// This will return error;
console.log(Person('John').getName());
```

it returns an error bcoz `Person()` by default returns `undefined` ,but if you use `new` it will return the newly created object.

```
// While this won't.
var p1 = new Person('john');
console.log(p1.getName());
```

this works bcoz a new object with `__proto__` set to `Person.prototype` is returned and since there is a `getName()` on it , it works as expected.

you may use scope safe constructor for your constructor to work without explicit `new`.

```
function Person(name) {
  if(this instanceof Person) {
    this.name = name;
  } else {
    return new Person(name);
  }
}
```

http://www.mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/9-new-scope-safe-constructors-in-oo-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) if you don't want to use the `new` keyword. Here's an example from MDN:

```
// Animal properties and method encapsulation
var Animal = {
  type: "Invertebrates", // Default value of properties
  displayType : function(){  // Method which will display type of Animal
    console.log(this.type);
  }
}

// Create new animal type called animal1 
var animal1 = Object.create(Animal);
animal1.displayType(); // Output:Invertebrates

// Create new animal type called Fishes
var fish = Object.create(Animal);
fish.type = "Fishes";
fish.displayType(); // Output:Fishes
```

Comment: I don't want to create 2 functions, there should be some way to get rid of "new" keyword.

Comment: @AhmedAlaa two functions?

Comment: Wow, Sorry missed here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have the `new` keyword all over your code (and I can't think of a good reason to want that, you would be basically hiding an important information), you could just do something like:

```
var pPerson = function(name) {
   this.name = name;
};

pPerson.prototype.getName = function () {
   return this.name;
};

var Person = function (name) {
    return new pPerson(name);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **really really hate your self**, you can do this

```
var Person = function(name) {
   var This = {}; 

   This.name = name;

   //See note
   Object.setPrototypeOf(This, arguments.callee.prototype);  

   return This;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function () {
   return this.name;
}

var p = Person('John');
console.log(p.getName());
```

**Note**
You absolutely have to read about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating prototype functions as a part of parent function itself.

```js
var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.get_name = function() {
    return this.name;
  }
  return this;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}

// This will return error;
console.log(Person('John').get_name());

// While this won't.
var p1 = new Person('john');
console.log(p1.getName());
```